# How to take give multiple options in python?

Tags: python-3.x

I was just wondering how to take multiple inputs in python? I want to have multiple options for my user to give input, suppose the user put in "Yes" instead of "yes" in the, my code would go to think that the user doesn't want a reminder. [Code example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rir5C.png), please check lines number 2 and 5. How would I do have the user get input with that user putting in either "yes" or "Yes"?

Comment: Please review [ask] and [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Post the code as text, not as an image.

Comment: [**PLEASE DO NOT POST TEXT AS IMAGES**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Copy and paste the text into your question and use the code formatting tool to format it correctly. Images are not searchable, and can not be interpreted by screen readers for those with visual impairments. Use the [edit] link to modify your question.

Comment: DorR = DorR.lower() add this before if statement. this will convert the string to lower case and Check

Answer (score 0):

The typical way to achieve this is lower()

https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_lower.asp

Just convert the input to lowercase (or uppercase, whatever matches your comparison).

edit, example:

`if DorR.lower() == "yes":`